# Finding rate of change of momentum in a fire extinguisher

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, integration

I am trying to find the rate of change of momentum as asked by part ii.

[image]

I have begun the question by saying "dp/dt= -dN/dt x momentum of a particle".

To cancel out the sqrt(pi) factor in dN/dt it seems like the integral "integral(x^2exp(-x^2))=sqrt(pi)/2" given in the paper must be use. But I don't see how finding the momentum of a particle could involve this as that integral would help in finding .
Any ideas?